# What other libraries does protobuf c++ depend on to compile the runtime?

Tags: c++, dependencies, shared-libraries, protocol-buffers

I just had a quick look at the documentation and the C++ source of the protocol buffers and I could not find any library requirements to build the protobuf runtime - either as shared library or static library.

Does anyone know what the requirements are?

*(I am suspecting that it only relies on C++ and the STL)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *(I am suspecting that it only relies on C++ and the STL)*

AFAIK you're suspecting right, there aren't any further dependencies.

**UPDATE:**
I have checked the docs again and couldn't find any mention for the need of other libraries to link the code generated by the protoc compiler (and I'm pretty sure they would have mentioned this).

We're using protobuf on embedded systems that run non standard OS (FreeRTOS actually), and I can't remember any difficulties with missing extra stuff necessary to integrate it. GCC 4.6 (arm-none-eabi) is used as cross toolchain.

Comment: Exactly, I also could not find anything in the docs. In the Thrift documentation they're very prompt at pointing out the requirements/dependencies.